# Mobile Google Chrome not sending the cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-chrome, cookies

I wrote a simple Express.js server which only sets a cookie named `hello-world` and returns the request headers. Here is the code:

```js
const app = require('express')()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('hello-world', 'this-is-the-value-of-cookie')
  res.json(req.headers)
})

app.listen(80, '0.0.0.0')
```

The problem is that mobile Google Chrome dose not send the cookies in the first request. Here is a demo of it: https://file.io/OIilmHoA2IKK

In the demo, I use the Android Studio's emulator and nip.io wildcard DNS. I simply start the Express.js server on my local machine and then access it via http://10.0.2.2.nip.io

As you can see in the demo, I first open the page and refresh to make sure `hello-world` cookie is set. Then I close Google Chrome and reopen it again. But the first time I open the page, there is still no `hello-world` cookie.

What did I do wrong here? I want the `hello-world` cookie be sent even in the first request after browser restarts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear from you code snippet, but I assume that you are creating a session cookie instead of a persistent cookie. Therefore the cookie is gone, when you close and reopen the browser.

You can create a persistent cookie by adding an expiration date to your cookie value. Your cookie will be stored until it expires (or is deleted by the user). That date parameter has to be formatted as a UTC string. You could do it like this:

```
res.cookie('hello-world', 'this-is-the-value-of-cookie', { expires: new Date(2030, 0) });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You were right. Setting the expire date keeps the cookie even after the restart of Google Chrome. Although your code was not working in Express.js v4. I edited it. It must be `res.cookie('hello-world', 'this-is-the-value-of-cookie', { expires: new Date(2030, 0) });`